# How to remove keystroke delays

Tags: windows, delay, keystrokes

When you browse thru web sites or office documents using up/down keys, there is a slight .5 second delay before the keystroke fires non-stop.

Is there a way to remove that .5 second delay from OS level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't said, I shall *assume* Windows:

In **Control Panel**, open up the **Keyboard** option and reduce the **Repeat Delay** setting to be shorter.

Comment: Yes, it is a Windows machine (Windows 7). There is still a slight a bit of a delay but this is what i wanted.  Thanks, DMA57361!

Comment: Still it is too slow, do you know any way of reducing it even more?